# htaccess 301 redirect from multiple urls to a single joomla site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

i have a joomla site set up on a server, with 4 urls directed to it.
I'd like to have 3 of those sites do a redirect to the 4th to improve the position of the website on the search engines.
if the urls were:

web1.com.ar
web1.com
www.web1.com.ar
www.web1.com

i'd like all of them to redirect trafic to www.web1.com

the problem is that I use joomla on the site, so 99% of the time people should be going into urls like "www.web1.com.ar/index.php/stuff/morestuff/something.html"

i don't want to loose any sort of bookmark people may have made, or my link on facebook.

i've been searching and trying to understand how this should be coded but i've had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file found in your root directory, if there is not one then rename the htaccess.txt to .htaccess and then around line 30 you should find this:

```
##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On
```

Then add this under it

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.web1\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1.com.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.web1.com.ar$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.web1\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Your links will still work but if any goes to the direct url they will be redirected.

You can also in your configuration.php look for the line that says:

```
var $live_site = '';
```

Change it to

```
var $live_site = 'http://www.web1.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?web1\.com\.ar|web1\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.web1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```